# How to select SQL rows where a spesific column is not the same value as another row?

Tags: mysql

I have a table with some columns, one of these are "email".
I want to select the rows in this table, where there is no duplicate value in "email".

Meaning if the table was like this:

```
id - email
10 - hello@hello.com
11 - bro@lift.com
12 - hello@hello.com
13 - hey@hello.com
```

The query would return only id 11 and 13, as 10 and 12 are duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Emails
WHERE email NOT IN(SELECT email
                   FROM emails
                   GROUP BY email
                   HAVING COUNT(email) > 1);
```

This will give you:

```
| ID |         EMAIL |
----------------------
| 11 |  bro@lift.com |
| 13 | hey@hello.com |
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2705f/1)

Answer (score 2):

I'll recommend the query that uses `JOIN`.

```
SELECT *
FROM tableName
WHERE email IN
    (
        SELECT email
        FROM    tableName
        GROUP BY email
        HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
    )
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2705f/3)

or using `JOIN`

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    tableName a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT email
            FROM    tableName
            GROUP BY email
            HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
        ) b ON a.email = b.email
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2705f/4)

for better performance, you use define an index on column `email`